# Can't open port 211 on Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-firewall

I have a windows 2003 server VPS and have installed [Projetex Server](http://projetex.com/product-info/benefits/) on it. Apparently, it uses Firebird as the database on port 211. However, my client connection attempts were unsuccessful - with the clients just reporting that port 211 is closed. My firewall is off. I checked with netstat, the port 211 isn't open.

I tried installing the server and client components on the same machine and the client connection succeeded there. External connections were still broken, though.

How do I fix it?

Comment: Have you talked to your VPS host's tech support to see if they block or reserve it?

Comment: Did you do a portscan on your vps? Did it tell you it was "open" or "filtered" ?

Answer (score 1):

> I checked with netstat, the port 211 isn't open

If the command you used to check was a `netstat -an | find /I ":211"` on your server then it simply tells you that you have not started any process which would listen for incoming connections at port 211. With this being the case, all firewall configuration is in vain - you need something there accepting connections in the first place.

As you aim to use [Projetex Server](http://aithelp.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/178/6/connection-to-projetex-server-failed-general-firewall-issues), this would mainly involve installing and starting the Projetex Server and making sure the database server (apparently a [Firebird](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebird_%28database_server%29) DBMS instance) is **[configured for accepting network connections](http://projetex.com/help/v9/index.html?internet_connection.htm)**. Running `netstat -an | find /I ":211"` should return at least one socket in *LISTEN* state at `your.ip.add.ress:211`

Comment: What can i do to listen in that port?

Comment: I run the firebird database on server, as http://projetex.com/help/v9/index.html?internet_connection.htm , it's ok. I try to connect to it remotely from projetex workstation by IP / port to server. It tells me that port 211 is closed.

Comment: i mean i installed both server and workstation projetex in both computers and the server is online. I tried installing them on one computer and the connection was established. I can't do it remotely. :(

Comment: @rakela *please post the netstat output*. And include the information that you are using Projetex with a Firebird database which is supposed to listen on port 211 in your question - it might help getting it re-opened.

Comment: I get nothing in output. http://tinypic.com/r/35cj5fl/6 :(
http://tinypic.com/r/dy0yzo/6

Comment: @rakela in this case, your Firebird server is not configured to listen on port 211. Consider using [**tcpview**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) to check what sockets fbserver.exe is listening to after startup. Also, the Projetex support might be a better advisor in the case the documentation does not apply to your installation for one reason or the other and the Firebird server simply is not supposed to use port 211 (apparently, version 7 used the default port 3050 so the port numbers seem not to be carved in stone with Projetex)

Comment: @rakela also note that Firebird supports a "Windows local" protocol mode where no TCP socket is used at all but database access is restricted to local processes only, This might be the reason for your observation of a working combined client/server setup on a single machine.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did fix it, by re installing the program on server.